# Share a working tree with git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose I have a library `Common` that may be used stand-alone, and is used by projects `P1` and `P2`, so the tree I want looks like

```
/Common/.git
        ...
/P1/.git
    .gitmodules  # points to remote server
    Common/
    ...
/P2/.git
    .gitmodules  # points to remote server
    Common/
    ...
```

When I make a change in `/Common`, I would like to be able to test it using `P1` and `P2` before committing.  With the usual `git submodule` command set, I would have to commit from `/Common`, push to remote, then pull from both `/P1/Common` and `/P2/Common`.  If the commit breaks something, it cannot be amended because the bad change has already been published.  Alternatively, I could `git remote add quicktest /Common` from `/P?/Common` to be able to pull without touching the remote server.  But this has lots of opportunities for inconsistency and it is dirty to strip broken commits from `/P?/Common` so that they can be amended in `/Common`.

I would rather that, during development, the working tree from `/Common` be used by `P1` and `P2`, but I can't make `/P1/Common` a symlink to `/Common` because `git submodule` recognizes the symlink as different from a directory.  Hardlinking directories is not allowed by most file systems.  I can hardlink all the files using

```
rm -rf /P1/Common
cp -rl /Common /P1/Common
```

which works quite well until a new file is added to `/Common` in which case this process needs to be repeated.  Is there an elegant way to both

1. keep `git clone --recursive git://remote/P1.git` working for the end user, and
2. allow me to easily test that changes in `/Common` work with `P1` and `P2`?

Comment: Try git worktree feature(since git 2.5) on your submodule. And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379818/git-possible-to-use-same-submodule-working-copy-by-multiple-projects/44649319#44649319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather establish an intermediate bare repo where to:

- push `Common` new commits
- pull from for `P1/Common` and `P2/Common`

At least, if commits are amended/removed later, that intermediate repo has never been published outside and you still can reset your `P1/Common` and `P2/Common` submodules to that intermediate repo content.

---

Update: if you are using [`git worktree`, since Git 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) (July 2015, 5 years after writing this answer), make sure to use [Git 2.25 (Q1 2020)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59202204/6309).
Before that,  "`git worktree add`" internally calls "`reset --hard`", which affected submodules.

Comment: I don't see what this intermediate repo buys me over pulling from the non-bare `/Common`.  I still have to commit to test, and if the test fails, it needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: @Jed: what it buys you is the possibility to force push to it, rewriting the history without any consequences for any other teammates.

Comment: Compare `git clone --bare /Common /Common-bare; cd /P1/Common; git remote add quicktest-bare /Common-bare` to `git remote add quicktest /Common`.  The bare repository doesn't seem to add anything, neither involves a remote.  But both of these have several steps to test a patch.  Cleaning out `/Common-bare` can be done with `git push -f`, but the extra indirection doesn't seem to add anything.  And, the point of my question is that I want to *reduce* the number of steps, not increase the number.

Comment: @Jed: then add `Common` (the local one, where you commit) as remote from `P1/Common` and `P2/Common` and *pull* directly from there.

Comment: Yes, that was described in the sentence "Alternatively, I could `git remote add quicktest /Common` from `/P?/Common` to be able to pull without touching the remote server."  The main problem is that cleaning up the clones at `/P1/Common` and `/P2/Common` is messy and easy to forget.  In particular, suppose that a change worked in `P1`, but not in `P2`.  After fixing the "obvious" typo that was causing the failure, one might `commit --amend` in `/Common`, then `pull -f` from `/P2/Common` and retest `P2`.  Assuming this passes, it would be natural to push `/Common`, commit `P1` and `P2`, ...

Comment: ... and push.  You might have noticed that `/P1/.gitmodules` now points to a revision that does not exist.  Maybe this is turning into a new feature, but I think it would be desirable to have `/P1/Common` as a symlink to `/Common` without git treating the symlink as a normal file (as far as submodule versioning is concerned).  I wonder why `git submodule` refuses to follow the symlink.

Comment: @Jed: Why don't have alias for those pulls? (alias that would pull from P1 and P2 each time)

Comment: I.e. shell script?  I dislike putting destructive operations in scripts, mostly because of error handling and (in other related cases) composability reasons.  But I think you are right that a shell script is adequate in this case.  Note that a shell script could also just `cp -rlTf /Common /P1/Common` and then committing would not even be required and edits of existing files would automatically be visible (without even running the above).

Comment: @Jed: note that alias can also be pure git commands, which would be compatible in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Try git worktree feature since git 2.5.

1. Delete `/P1/Common`
2. cd `/Common`
3. Create `P1` branch for the coming `/P1/Common` working tree
4. run `git worktree add ../P1/Common P1`

Do the same thing on `/P2`.

Then, `/P1/Common`, `/P2/Common and`/Common`working trees share the same repository`/Common/.git`.

And you can easily just checkout any commit which is commit in another working tree.

P.S. you can still use git submodule command for daily work with this git worktree feature.