# Git repo where each submodule is a branch of same repo. How to avoid double/triple... download with git clone --recursive?

Tags: git

Suppose I have the following project tree:

```
src
data
doc
```

I'd like to keep all the folders in a Git repository, published to Gitlab. But I don't want to track `data` and `doc` together with `src`.

So I use the following strategy:

```
git remote add origin ADDRESS
git submodule add -b data ADDRESS data
git submodule add -b doc ADDRESS doc
```

It actually works fine, except when I try to replicate the repository with:

```
git clone --recursive ADDRESS
```

all objects get transmitted 3 times: both the root and `data` and `doc` all contain:

- origin/master
- origin/data
- origin/doc

Is there an easy way to avoid this? Just to clarify what I'd like:

- the master repository should only fetch `origin/master`, not the other two
- the data submodule should only fetch `origin/data`.
- the doc submodule should only fetch `origin/doc`.

Would be easy to achieve with 3 separate repositories, but that's too cumbersome, since I apply this approach for multiple projects.

### UPDATE

`git worktree` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415914/1350992) allows me to achieve what I want manually.

But now, instead of the automatic approach (which consumes 4x bandwidth):

```
git clone --recursive git@foo:foo/bar.git
```

I have to do:

```
git clone git@foo:foo/bar.git
cd bar
git worktree add data origin/data
git worktree add src/notebooks origin/notebooks
git worktree add doc origin/doc
git worktree add reports origin/reports
```

I could automate this process with some scripts, since `.gitmodules` file already contains the complete info:

```
[submodule "data"]
    path = data
    url = git@foo:foo/bar.git
    branch = data
[submodule "src/notebooks"]
    path = src/notebooks
    url = git@foo:foo/bar.git
    branch = notebooks
[submodule "doc"]
    path = doc
    url = git@foo:foo/bar.git
    branch = doc
[submodule "reports"]
    path = reports
    url = git@foo:foo/bar.git
    branch = reports
```

I wonder if there already is some standard git script or flag that handles this?

Comment: You can tell Git to do single-branch clones. I would not recommend this in general, but it should work for this particular case.

Comment: *But I don't want to track data and doc together with src.* Is there any sound reason for that?

Comment: Data and source code are separate concepts. Source code are text files that you can grep and review. Data are usually binary blobs. I wonder if there is any sound reason to mix them.

Answer (score 4):

Git is designed to be distributed, that means every user should have whole history and all branches. If you want to have a single bare repo, but different working trees to reduce network traffic, you can do it using `git worktree` command:

So in your case, let's say you have a `src` folder as a main folder with src branch, creating other two from it should be as simple as

```
git worktree add ../data data
git worktree add ../doc doc
```

See this awesome answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/3066081 to get more info about this command. But if you have an older git without worktree support, you can use `git-new-workdir` script as

```
git-new-workdir project-dir new-workdir branch
```

This is also described in [Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git)

Comment: Thanks. I'll award the bounty before it disappears. Maybe someone can still answer if it's possible to automate the clone using `git worktree`.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: "[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) add" internally calls "`reset --hard`" that should not descend into submodules, even when `submodule.recurse` configuration is set, but it was affected.

This has been corrected with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

See [commit 4782cf2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4782cf2ab686bacca8d2908319981ac27d54ca25) (27 Oct 2019) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 05fc647](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05fc6471e3668f17b665ec686d5629e92df917fa), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4782cf2ab686bacca8d2908319981ac27d54ca25): teach "add" to ignore submodule.recurse config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
>
> "`git worktree add`" internally calls "`reset --hard`", but if `submodule.recurse` is set, reset tries to recurse into initialized submodules, which makes `start_command` try to `cd` into non-existing submodule paths and die.
>
> Fix that by making sure that the call to reset in "`worktree add`" does not recurse.